# How can we write unit test for MediaPlayer Utility class

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a utility method as following:

```
private fun initializeAndPlay(mediaId: Int) {
            Logger.d(MediaPlayerUtil::class.java, "Initializing MediaPlayer on Thread", Thread.currentThread().name)
            val applicationContext = MyApplication.getInstance()
            val uri =
                Uri.parse("android.resource://" + applicationContext.packageName + "/" + mediaId)
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(applicationContext, uri)
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener { obj: MediaPlayer ->
                Logger.d(MediaPlayerUtil::class.java, "MediaPlayer OnPrepared()", Thread.currentThread().name)
                obj.start()
            }
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { obj: MediaPlayer ->
                Logger.d(MediaPlayerUtil::class.java, "MediaPlayer onCompletion()", Thread.currentThread().name)
                obj.release()
            }
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
        }
```

How can I write unit test for this? Please suggest

Comment: What do you want to test, exactly?

Comment: Want to test whether we have received the callback in setOnCompletionListener() or not.

Comment: This is testing MediaPlayer implementation, so presumably not your concern

Answer (score 1):

Your function does not have any publicly-observable effects, that's why it's hard to test. You can change it in the following way:

Step 1. Introduce a callback interface that your function will be invoking:

```
interface MediaPlayerCallbacks {
  fun onPrepared(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer)
  fun onCompletion(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer)
}

private fun initializeAndPlay(mediaId: Int, callbacks: MediaPlayerCallbacks) {
  ...
  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener { obj: MediaPlayer ->
    callbacks.onPrepared(obj)
  }
  mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener { obj: MediaPlayer ->
    callbacks.onCompletion(obj)
  }
  ...
}
```

Step 2. Pass a real implementation of callbacks in production code:

```
val callbacks = object : MediaPlayerCallbacks {
  fun onPrepared(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    Logger.d(MediaPlayerUtil::class.java, "MediaPlayer OnPrepared()", Thread.currentThread().name)
    mediaPlayer.start()      
  }

  fun onCompletion(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    Logger.d(MediaPlayerUtil::class.java, "MediaPlayer onCompletion()", Thread.currentThread().name)
    mediaPlayer.release()
  }
}
initializeAndPlay(mediaId, callbacks)
```

Step 3. Pass a fake implementation in your tests that you can use for assertions.

```
val callbacks = object : MediaPlayerCallbacks {
  var prepared = false
  var completed = false
  
  fun onPrepared(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    prepared = true      
  }

  fun onCompletion(mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer) {
    completed = true
  }
}

initializeAndPlay(mediaId, callbacks)

assertTrue(callbacks.prepared)
assertTrue(callbacks.completed)
```